# Set width of HR tag using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The fluff: This is an assignment, I'm required to create and manipulate the hr tag using javascript. I am required to insert the .js file directly after the opening body tag.

The problem: I cannot get the width property of hr to apply.

I have tried both setAttribute() and .style.width = blah. Neither have worked for me. Where am I going wrong?

```js
function headerFunction() {
  var h1 = document.getElementById('h1');
  h1.innerHTML = "L. Name";
  h1.style.color = "red";
  h1.style.fontFamily = "Tahoma";
  h1.setAttribute("align", "center");

  var h2 = document.getElementById('h2');
  h2.innerHTML = "WEB 101.0001";
  h2.style.color = "red";
  h2.style.fontFamily = "Garamond";
  h2.setAttribute("align", "center");
  h2.style.fontStyle = "italic";

  var h3 = document.getElementById('h3');
  h3.innerHTML = "Build Your Resume";
  h3.setAttribute("align", "center");

  var newElem = document.createElement("HR");
  var hR = document.getElementById('header');
  hR.insertBefore(newElem, hR.childNodes[4]);
  var hrule = document.getElementsByTagName("HR");
  hrule.setAttribute("width", "60%");
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="finalCSS.css">
<title>Web 115 Final Project</title>

</head>

<body onload="headerFunction()">
  <script src="projectJS.js"></script>
 <header id="header">
    <h1 id="h1"></h1>
    <h2 id="h2"></h2>
    <h3 id="h3"></h3>
  </header>
  <form action="" name="form1">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Learn to use your developer console. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: Read about `getElementsByTagName` and you will see it is an HTML Collection

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML` to set text: it's slow (as it requires parsing for HTML) and risky (due to script injection attacks). Use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: @Dai thank you for the info, I will have to read more about .textContent. I'm at the end of my class and we haven't covered that at all surprisingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use your browser's developer tools to check the error console and see that you're getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: hrule.setAttribute is not a function

That implies that `hurle` isn't what you think it is.  You're treating it like an element, but really you're getting back an array of elements.  You probably want the first one, so you would reference that as `hrule[0]`.

From there, you can set the width with `.style` as you tried earlier.